# Как сделать так что-бы человек мог удалить себя из таблицы в базе данных, только себя. PHP

Tags: php, база-данных, mysqli

**Есть блок который выводит всех людей в таблицу**

```
include('connect.php');

$query ="SELECT * FROM patrul";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

if($result)
{
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); // количество полученных строк
    echo "<table class='table text-center table-striped table-dark'><thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope='col'>Name officer</th>
      <th scope='col'>Surname officer</th>
      <th scope='col'>Now in patrol</th>
    </tr>
</thead>";
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
            echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
            echo "<td>PO#" . $row[3] .' '. 'to disp: '. $row[4] . ' ' . ', 10-20: ' . $row[5] . ', ' . $row[6] . ', over**' ."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<thead class='thead-dark'>
    <tr>
      <th scope='col'>Name officer</th>
      <th scope='col'>Surname officer</th>
      <th scope='col'>Now in patrol</th>
    </tr>
</thead>";
    echo "</table>";
```

**Под таблицей есть две кнопки добавить и удалить, вся проблема в том, что когда нажимаю удалить оно удаляет последнюю запись в таблице а не ту который оставил пользователь**

Кнопка удаления

```
<form method="POST"><a class="btn btn-primary" name='submit' href="?patrul=<?= $row[0]?>" role="button">Resign</a></form>
```

И вверху страницы есть скрипт который по GET удаляет запись

```
if (isset($_GET['patrul'])) {
    $patrul = $_GET['patrul'];
    $query ="DELETE FROM patrul WHERE id=$patrul";
    mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));     
}
```

Не пойму как сделать что-бы пользователь удалял только свою запись которую он и оставил..

Comment: Какие ещё поля есть в таблице patrul?

Comment: id name surname badge situation add_info available_info

Comment: А где user_id? Как определить, кто автор? Или это и есть пользователи?

Comment: У вас вообще есть аутентификация?

Comment: у меня в базе данных много таблиц, но эта именно для пользователей, задумка такая, это сайт игры, и там есть полиция, когда офицеры выходят в патрули они должны оставить себя в таблице, это сделано, и данные именно определённого пользователя подставляются, но удаление нужно сделать что-бы человек мог только себя, а аутентификация вы имеете ввиду при заходе на сайт пароль и логин? если вы про это - то есть.

Comment: Ну вот, вместо подстановки данных пользователя в патруль нужно добавить идентификатор настоящего пользователя(таблица users, по которой вы аутентифицируете пользователя)... Потом, сравнивая user_id патруля и id залогиненного пользователя вы сможете принимать решение, удалять или нет.

Comment: так user_id всё время будет меняться так-как id залогиненного пользователя всегда один и тоже, а user_id меняется.

Comment: Что значит меняться? При добавлении строчки в patr**u**l сохраняйте id залогиненного пользователя в этой строчке. Пусть это будет не user_id, а id_zologinennogo_polzovatelya, это же не важно.

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое <33